# How to check if Flash CAN be installed in a browser from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, browser

I would like to check if Flash is supported on the platform that hosts the browser. I don't want to check is it is installed (I know how to do that). I just want to know if it's reasonable to suggest to the user to install Flash plugin. If the page is viewed from iOS device that does not support Flash, I don't want to show "Please install flash" message - I will display HTML5 version of the control then.

I know that one solution is check for iPad/iPhone/iPod in useragent to detect apple, but is there some library that check for more than only apple?

Comment: you can check the browser this way http://www.ajaxera.com/javascript-detect-iphone/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then instead of showing the "Please install Flash" text, show instead the HTML5 version of the control. Put that HTML5 code where the "Please install Flash" is.

---

Additionally, it's easier (more like advisable) to use HTML5 first then fall back to Flash if not supported. Something like this:

```
<video src="html5_video_url">

    <!-- contents in here are only shown when video is not supported -->
    <embed src="flash_video_url"/>

</video>
```

Also, UA detection isn't advisable since it can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of iThings there are several problems with version-to-browser and version-to-system matches of the player, or rather versions of the player and the systems it is intended to run on.

The difficulties are as follows: there isn't a 64-bit version for Linux (a debugger had never existed and the player codenamed Square, afaik is just a wrapper around 32-bit application).

On free systems, where the vendor doesn't tell you what software you are not allowed to install... technically, whatever application can interface with NPAPI (Netscape Plugin API) can be used as a plugin to the browser that implements these API. There's a newer version of these API, which Netscape doesn't want to implement, (actually, no one except Google Chrome implemented them), the version also known as Pepper Plugin API.

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no way to use JavaScript to test for NPAPI availability. If you had this, you could weed out all browsers that technically can't display any plugins, Flash included. I would imagine there must be some indirect way to do that, some browser functionality that would be present if the interface existed or something like that, but can't think of anything at the moment... Of course, there are ActiveX too. So, the course of action would be to first test for NPAPI, if not that, then, perhaps, AX, and if not that, then certainly, there's no way the browser can run Flash (which, unfortunately, doesn't guarantee Flash will indeed work).